# Select values from table based on order preference and availability - Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following table:
[image: order-preference]

These are the order preference of some people based on the position (each column is a position).

In another page I have the availability of those people to fit that positions:

[image: availability]

I would like to extract a determined number of people (Example: 2xF, 2xP, 1xPS, 4xR, 5xS, 1xWS, 2xDM) based on their availability and order but considering that they cannot fit two positions neither.

This is what I tried for DM (Very inefficient and not considering that they cannot fit two roles at the same time):

[image: attempt]

Formula: `=IF(VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R3,Apto!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R3,Apto!A:B,1,0),IF(VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R4,Apto!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R4,Apto!A:B,1,0),IF(VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R5,Apto!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R5,Apto!A:B,1,0),IF(VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R6,Apto!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R6,Apto!A:B,1,0),IF(VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R7,Apto!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R7,Apto!A:B,1,0),IF(VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R8,Apto!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R8,Apto!A:B,1,0),IF(VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R9,Apto!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R9,Apto!A:B,1,0),IF(VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R10,Apto!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP('Pivot Puestos'!R10,Apto!A:B,1,0),"No Disponible"))))))))`

Comment: Please use [edit] to repost including both your tables as [markdown tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) as well; to go with the images. That way we can copy paste them. The link I shared has the option to accept copy paste from Excel into it and then generate a markdown table. You then add that markdown table into your question, highlight the entire table and press Ctrl + K.

Comment: Do you need to add a check that the times N you attempt to select person x is not greater than the number of available slots (_Nax_) for person x? Or can you assume _Nax_ <= N ?

Comment: The problem seems ill-defined. You haven't described what criteria you are using to judge between possible assignments. A table of preferences does not easily map to a single objective function. My guess is that once you clarify exactly what it is that you are trying to do, you will have a non-trivial combinatorial optimization problem. VBA (rather than just spreadsheet formulas) is probably required.

Comment: Also, according to your description a role is the columns so DM is a role. So, are you saying that if person Name 10 and Name 11 have already been picked for role DM, when you come to pick for next role these people should have been removed in some way and not eligible for picking?

Comment: @JohnColeman Sounds like you have a better handle on what is required. To me it does sound like an optimization problem and one where I think I would need to remove people during picks from the available pool but don't understand the rules well enough to model.

Comment: @QHarr I agree that the rules are not clear enough to model. This sounds like it *could* be an interesting question to work on, but it needs to be clearly specified first. My guess is that in an optimal solution you probably have to pick less-preferred candidates for some positions to free up other candidates for other positions. The interactions between the choices might be difficult to resolve. Maybe it is some variation of the [Rank-maximal allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-maximal_allocation) problem.